# WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity with CKEditor image upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor, carrierwave

When I try to upload an image with CKEditor I get the error `WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity`  and the following:

```
Started POST "/ckeditor/attachment_files?CKEditor=blog_entry_body&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-28 18:38:57 -0500
Processing by Ckeditor::AttachmentFilesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"upload"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000000231fef0 @original_filename="me.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload\"; filename=\"me.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20130528-13870-17wbprr>>, "CKEditor"=>"blog_entry_body", "CKEditorFuncNum"=>"1", "langCode"=>"en"}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'M96bQAv-NGdidsn7hypOJA' LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
(0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 0.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

It looks like it's happening in `Ckeditor::AttachmentFilesController#create`. But I didn't see this controller get generated when I installed the CKEditor gem. I found in another post that I must `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` but like I said, I don't see `Ckeditor::AttachmentFilesController#create`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the [ckeditor gem](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor), you can find the controller here:

https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/tree/master/app/controllers/ckeditor

However, it looks their config.js has a solution for csrf, IMHO, it's better than doing the `skip_before_filer` in the controller.
See config.js here:

https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js